Projecting an ellipsoid onto the coordinate axes
I'm working on a problem of prediction intervals. Consider a vector-valued random variable $\mathbf{X} \in R^K$ distributed as a multivariate Gaussian with zero mean and covariance matrix $\mathbf{\Sigma}$. Let $d = F_{\mathbf{\Sigma}}^{-1}(1-\delta; K)$ be the squared Mahalanobis distance that defines an ellipsoid that contains $1-\delta$ of the probability mass. Here $F$ is the cumulative distribution function of the $\chi^2$ distribution with $K$ degrees of freedom. This defines a minimum volume set that contains the value of $\mathbf{X}$ with probability $1-\delta$. In some applications, we want to compute the axis-parallel hyperrectangle that exactly circumscribes this ellipsoid. Here is the simplest version of the problem:
Consider an ellipsoid centered at the origin defined by
$$\mathbf{x}^\top \mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1} \mathbf{x} = d$$
where $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ is a covariance matrix with diagonal entries equal to 1 and off-diagonal entries equal to $\rho\in[0,1]$, and $d>0$ is the "radius" (as the squared Mahalanobis distance). For each dimension $k = 1, \ldots, K$, solve the optimization problem
$$
\mathrm{arg}\max_{x_k} \quad\mbox{ such that }\quad \mathbf{x}^\top \mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1} \mathbf{x} = d
$$
Is a closed-form solution possible for $K>2$ for general $\rho$? By symmetry, the answers will be the same for all dimensions $k$.
